# Prompt for file path: home directory alias and case-sensitive tab completion

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script that prompts the user for a file path:

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH
```

I am then using this file path to perform operations – namely to compress a folder.

```
(cd "$FILEPATH"; tar -cvz *) > /tmp/torrent.tar.gz;
```

At the prompt, if I use the `~` alias (home directory), then the shell script doesn't seem to understand this, as the `tar` function compresses the wrong path. Is there anyway I can allow for this alias?

Also, tab completion seems to be case-sensitive at the prompt. I was wondering how I can change that?

Comment: Woe is to he who must debug shell.  The weeping tears of sysadmins everywhere line the path you travel.  Tread softly.

Comment: I’m learning! Or trying to.

Answer (score 1):

Example using eval:

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH
eval FILEPATH=$FILEPATH
cd $FILEPATH
echo $PWD
```

In your case it becomes:

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH
eval FILEPATH=$FILEPATH
(cd "$FILEPATH"; tar -cvz *) > /tmp/torrent.tar.gz;
```

To deal with spaces you can use sed:

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH
FILEPATH=$(echo $FILEPATH | sed 's/ /\\ /')
eval FILEPATH=$FILEPATH
cd "$FILEPATH"
echo $PWD
```

Comment: Using your first chunk of code, if I input a path that has spaces in it, such as `~/Desktop/Hello\ My\ Name\ is\ Oliver`, the file path will not be recognised. I tried wrapping double quotes around $FILEPATH to no avail: `read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH; eval FILEPATH="$FILEPATH"; echo "$FILEPATH"`

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the substitution yourself like this:

```
filepath=${filepath/\~/$HOME}
```

I don't know whether there's a way to get the shell to do it for you.

Here's an answer to your other question: https://superuser.com/questions/90196/case-insensitive-tab-completion-in-bash

Comment: Thanks. Tab completion is not case sensitive, until I get to the prompt here. In all other uses it is not case sensitive.